# Unable to parse page for field values error in ULS log

Tags: parser-error, error, publishing-site

We get this error on every page request on our Production environment. All other environments are ok. The environment has been upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010.

> Unable to parse page for field values: The
>   'mso:CustomDocumentProperties' start tag on line 2 does not match the
>   end tag of 'mso:PublishingStartDate'. Line 44, position 23.,
>   pageContent = "<%@ Page
>   Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.
>   Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
>   %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference
>   VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register
>   Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
>   Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>    
>     1073741823</mso:PublishingContact> 
>   System
>   Account</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact>
>   </mso:PublishingContactPicture> 
>   </mso:PublishingContactName>  0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130E
>   C3DB064584E219954237AF39009E37208CA80D314C9C304EC2084939
>   67010086F9211366BBDA4080E04AAF3338ABBF</mso:ContentTypeId> 
>   </mso:Comments> 
>   </mso:PublishingContactEmail> 
>   xxxxxxxxx, Front
>   page</mso:PublishingPageLayout>              velkommen til oss
>   </mso:PublishingPageContent>  2009-09-11T15:14:00Z</mso:FirstTimePublished> 
>   xxxxxxxxxx</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_ApprovedBy>
>   537</mso:ApprovedBy> 
>   <div
>   title="_schemaversion" id="_3">    <div
>   title="_view">      <span
>   title="_columns">1</span>      <span
>   title="_linkstyle"></span>      <span
>   title="_groupstyle"></span>    </div> 
>   </div></mso:SummaryLinks>  0x2872E02F9792B480A2378F313E901ABC86D
>   DF2D7058B04BF917EA7D4DE32975968E6C04CE07D79CF9CFB68C05C
>   5B81353ADA289BCF7777BC740F265F2B510C61,10 Feb 2011 09:07:23
>   -0000</mso:SBN_SaveSucceededRequestDigest> 
>   2511</mso:SBN_SaveSucceededField>  0</mso:HighPriority>  0</mso:ExpiryEnabled>  1</mso:PrimaryLanguageVersion>  69974afd53774adfb7d0559f1b61fc3f</mso:PageId> 
>   </mso:FrontPageArticleImage>  a85b4b42e20047898c6555250ea4a055</mso:OtherPageId> 
>   </mso:PublishingRollupImage>  English</mso:PageLanguage> 
>   </mso:FrontPageArticleImageSmall>  </mso:SummaryText>  </mso:Audience>  </mso:LinkToOtherLanguageVersion>  xxxxx Section Page</mso:ContentType> 
>   Norwegian</mso:OtherPageLanguage>  -1791795021.00000</mso:PageGroupId> 
>   1688093000</mso:LanguageConnectionId> 
>   0</mso:ScheduleEndNotificationIntervalUnit> 
>   0</mso:ScheduleEndNotificationInterval> 
>   2010-11-19T12:00:00Z</mso:PublishingStartDate> 
>   0</mso:ReviewRequestIntervalUnit> 
>   0</mso:ReviewRequestInterval> 
>   2011-01-05T14:00:00Z</mso:PublishingStartDate> 
>   2011-02-09T07:35:00Z</mso:PublishingStartDate>  False</mso:RequiresRouting> 
>   </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
>   </xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs>  xxxxx 
>     
>   </mso:CustomDocumentProperties> </xml>      
>   </mso:CustomDocumentProperties> </xml>      
>   </mso:CustomDocumentProperties> </xml>  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some similar errors in an upgrade I had to troubleshoot.  We found that the upgrade was not completed successfully in that case, and that there were some problems mapping the publishing features and page layouts.

I would double check the upgrade logs and also recommend running the following stsadm command.
stsadm -o localupgradestatus

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263319(office.12).aspx

which is a good way to validate the current status of the farm.

Answer (score 2):

Is your PageLayout screwed on your production environment? Looks like a tag is missing.